# Create LINQ on the DataTable for getting RowNumber

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT distinct ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductId desc) AS Ranking,
 ProductId,
 ProductName,
 FROM View_AllArt) 
 AS foo 
 WHERE Ranking > " + i + " AND Ranking <= (" + (j) + ")
```

`i` and `j` are the veriable with some integer values.

how i can write the LINQ query as like this SQL query,where my `View_AllArt` will become the `dtAccount` table.
(I want to create LINQ on DataTable).

Answer (score 0):

If you return the results, you can filter the list by ranking like this:

```
var table = GetDataTable(); //retrieve the data

int i = 10;
int j = 20;

table = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("Ranking") >= i && r.Field<int>("Ranking") <= j).AsDataView.ToTable();
```

**EDIT**

You might be able to avoid returning the row number using the row index of the `DataTable`:

```
table = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => table.Rows.IndexOf(r) >= i && table.Rows.IndexOf(r) <= j).AsDataView().ToTable();
```

Comment: hi @James Johnson,thanks for instant reply,but can you tell me how i can get the DataTable with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: If you put it in the `SELECT` statement like in your example above, it should be returned as a column in the results.